# Implement linux/bash date snippet in java/groovy

Tags: bash, groovy

In bash I have:

```
  if [[ "$( date -d "${itemTime}" +%s)" -lt  "$( date -d "$1 days ago" +%s )" ]]; then
      echo "go do"
  fi
```

So basically do some operation if the `${itemTime}` is more that `$1` days old.

Example of `${itemTime}` could be: `2018-02-19T13:39:15Z`

In java I have:

```
String tt = "2018-02-19T13:39:15Z";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
Date dt = sdf.parse(tt);
long epoch = dt.getTime();
int res = (int)(epoch/1000);
System.out.println(res);

int days = 1;
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate tenDaysAgo = now.minusDays(days);

ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); 
long epochs = tenDaysAgo.atStartOfDay(zoneId).toEpochSecond();
System.out.println(epochs);
```

it gives:

```
1519047555
1518994800
```

Now when I run this from bash (at the same time):

```
  echo $( date -d "2018-02-19T13:39:15Z" +%s)
  echo $( date -d "1 days ago" +%s )
```

I get:

```
1519047555
1519053480
```

So  the first value is identical. But why does the second value diff "so much":

**1518994800** (java)

vs

**1519053480** (bash)

?

Comment: So what is not working here? what is the value of `$1` you are passing?

Comment: I updated the post, for some reason I get two different times for current time minus one day in bash and in java.

Comment: Java is at midnight yesterday, bash is just 24 hours ago

Comment: Hm is there some documentation for that, pages that explains a bit about this, did not find anything on google about that.

Comment: Why are you applying the `atStartOfDay()` method only for Java code?  Its equivalence in bash will be `date -d "1 days ago 0"`.If you just want to subtract one day rather than calculating the midnight time in epoch, just say `tenDaysAgo.toEpochSecond()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want roughly a day and you don't care for all the things that can happen with timezones and DST etc, this is a straight forward solution:

```
def itemTime = Instant.parse("2018-02-19T13:39:15Z")
// ===> 2018-02-19T13:39:15Z
if (itemTime.isBefore(Instant.now().minusSeconds(60*60*24))) { println "TODO" }
// prints: TODO
```

Comment: Ok that much simpler. Not critical, for some reason println "Current time is: " + Instant.now().toString() prints the time one hour earlier than my workstation time. So Instant.now() does not use current system time on my machine?

Comment: Yes.  Instant is UTC.  And the string you pass in (in your example) is zone-less.  So i assumed Instant.